# Play sound file one after another in android

Tags: android

I am trying to play sound in android one after from "res/raw" folder. But it is only playing the first sound from sounds array. is there any other way to do it?

There is three sound file in raw folder

> 1.aa.ogg
>   2.ma.ogg
>   3.ar.ogg

```
package com.protonray.calculatorplus;    
import java.util.List;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;


    public class LayoutNew extends Activity{
        int count=0;
        int[] sounds={R.raw.aa,R.raw.ma,R.raw.ar };
        MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_new);        
            Button play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.play);       
            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    count =0 ;
            //Play the Frist sound
                    mp =MediaPlayer.create(LayoutNew.this,sounds[count]);               
                    mp.start();
                    count =1 ;          
                }
            });





mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {         
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(count<3){                    
                            mp.stop();
//Play next sound                   
                            mp =MediaPlayer.create(LayoutNew.this,sounds[count]);
                            mp.start();
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [setNextMediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29). That should accomplish what you need.

Simply create 3 media players (one for each sound file) in `onClick` and then set the next player for the first two files to the next file's player, for example:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       for ( int snd = 0; snd < 3; snd++ )  {
          mp[snd] = MediaPlayer.create( LayoutNew.this, sounds[snd] );               
       }
       for ( int snd = 0; snd < 2; snd++ )  {
          mp[snd].setNextMediaPlayer( mp[snd+1] );
       }           
    );
```

You should also release all 3 media players when they complete (by calling `release()` on each of them). This could be done easily by adding an `onCompletion` handler to the **LAST** media player **ONLY** (i.e. `mp[2]`), so that it does the cleanup once all 3 sounds have completed playing.

---

Edit, since you require API 8, you can use the method you do currently, but you will have to set the `OnCompletionListener` for both the first AND second sounds, currently it will only trigger when the first one finishes, not the second one. Try this code:

```
MediaPlayer mp;

play.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
      mp = MediaPlayer.create( LayoutNew.this, sounds[0] );
      mp.start();
      mp.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.dispose();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create( LayoutNew.this, sounds[1] );
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                  mp.dispose();
                  mp = MediaPlayer.create( LayoutNew.this, sounds[2] );
                  mp.start();
                  mp.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener() {
                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.dispose();
                        mp = null;
                     }
                  });
               }
            });
         }
      });
   }
}
```

I did not test this code, but it should work. The key thing to take away from this is that you need to call `setOnCompletionListener` each time you create a new MediaPlayer, so that the new instance will notify you when it completes.

Also, because you are setting everything up in `onClick` (all at once) you do not need to use a counter unless you really want to, or have some other good reason for it. Either way, this should illustrate sufficiently what you were doing wrong and how to do it so that it works.

Comment: setNextMediaPlayer(arg0) method is not supported in API level 8...What should i do now?

Comment: Then you can use the method you currently use in your code, but with a few changes. I have added that to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you....actually sounds file is not constant..its dynamic..i have solve the problem using recurring function....

Answer (score 0):

Just judging by your code, try placing your `mp.setOnCompletionListener` inside of the `onClick`. Also I don't think you need the `mp.stop`

Comment: thank you....it has worked partially....i have placed "mp.setOnCompletionListener" inside "onclick"

it only works one time that means only play sounds[0] and sounds[1].
can you tell me what is the problem here please?

Comment: Personally I think you are doing too much work, I just do a `whileloop` within your `onClick` method and create a `playSound` method that handles the MediaPLayer. Pseudocode: `While(i<=numberOfSounds){playSound(i) i++}` and make sure you are releasing the `MediaPlayer` when necessary

Comment: that halts the entire activity until all the audio files are played.